# Selection autofill in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Basically I added a formula in cell A1 with:

`ws["A1"] = B1 + C1`

But I need this formula to go down until A260, where it will be B260+C260.

In VBA there is a formula "selection autofill" for it, is there anything similar in openpyxl? I found nothing in google about this.

Comment: openpyxl is a library for the file format and not a replacement for an application. But it's pretty easy to write the code to do what you want in Python.

Comment: what would you recommend to use for excel then? @CharlieClark